# libpq c++ ошибка выполнения

Tags: windows, postgresql, libpq

Написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb("host=localhost post=3010 dbname=postgres username=postgres password=admin123");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD)
    {
        printf("Connection error\n");
        PQfinish(conn);
        return -1; //Execution of the program will stop here
    }
    printf("Connection ok\n");
    //End connection
    PQfinish(conn);
    printf("Disconnected\n");
}
```

В `visual studio`:

1. поставил `debug x64`
2. C/C++ > Общие > Дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов += `"D:\Programs\PostgreSQL\include"`
3. Компоновщик > Общие > Дополнительные каталоги библиотек += `"D:\Programs\PostgreSQL\lib"`
4. Компоновщик > Ввод > Дополнительные зависимости += `"libpq.lib"`  `// объясните зачем это`

Скомпилировал, ошибок нет.

Запустил:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего эта ошибка? Как решить?

UPD: Установил все необходимые dll и поместил их в папку с exe-шником.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое post=3010 в строке коннекта? Опечатка в слове port?

Comment: @gbg дыаа))))))

Comment: А почему номер порта такой экзотический? У постгреса это 5432 по умолчанию. Вы его меняли?

Comment: @gbg да менял))

Comment: Итого, у вас две проблемы. Разбирайтесь, почему у вас dll потерялась и исправляйте строку подключения. Возможно, вылезет еще что-то.

Comment: @gbg посмотрите upd пожалуйста

Comment: читайте вторую часть моего ответа, про утилиту просмотра зависимостей.

Comment: @gbg при чем тут зависимости? Я их все нашел и подключил. Тут какая-то ошибка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110194/discussion-between-gbg-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Это сообщение однозначно говорит о том, что `Windows` не смогла загрузить `libpq.dll`.

В папке с программой или по путям, прописанным в переменной `PATH` либо нет самой `dll`, либо какой-то из `dll`, от которых она зависит.

**Просмотреть зависимости** можно [этим инструментом](http://dependencywalker.com)

Comment: так у меня не dll а lib

Comment: lib содержит в себе ссылки на dll, если не настроена статическая компоновка. А она у вас, скорее всего, не настроена.